# Variables set in response of jQuery post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jQuery post requests a lot. I understand that when you are working within the response the variables have their own scope. Is there a good way to set variables in the response but have those variables available outside of the post? Like for other functions in JS.

Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
 $.post('URL', { }, function(data) {

    var cData = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(cData, function(k, v) {

      var cID = v.id;  

  });
```

So what I do that I cannot access cID outside of the post request. Is there a way to make this work?

Any help would be great.
Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is a sample I just tested:

```
var savedCount;

$.post('/app/actions/countsAction.php', { call: "getCountFullByID", countID: countID}, function(data) {

    savedCount = 1;
    alert(savedCount);

});

alert(savedCount);
```

I get 2 alerts when I run this. The first one is a 1 when the alert is fired off in the $.post and the second one is undefined.

Comment: The bottom `alert` fires immediately after the request is sent to the server, before the response is received.  So yes, it will be undefined.  The `alert` in the `$.post` callback will happen after `savedCount` is set, and will be one.  At that point, the value of `savedCount` *outside* of the `$.post` call is set as well.

Comment: it's because ajax is asynchronous.. so the second alert is firing before the post function successfully completes - causing the undefined..

Comment: How are you using that `cID` variable? This may be an issue with asynchronous callbacks, where the code using `cID` is running before your `$.post` is completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare your variable outside of the `$.post` call:

```
var cID;
$.post('URL', function(data) {
    var cData = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(cData, function(k, v) {
        cID = v.id;  
    });
});
```

...not sure what you're attempting to do with that though, as you're looping over a collection and continually (re)setting the value of a single variable.  If you need to keep track of all the variables, consider holding the values in (maybe) an Array.

**EDIT**
If you need to do a *synchronous* ("blocking") `$.post` call, you can.  From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `asynch` function parameter:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried that. I normally declare my variables outside. When I do that the variable is undefined or if I declare it with a 0 and then in the $.post it get's set to another value it is still 0 outside of the post. Also, this was just a sample I put together. I realize setting the variable in the loop will just overwrite it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, no, if you're doing this correctly it will work as you're wanting.  If "the variable is undefined" you're doing something else wrong.  Post some code.

Comment: Yeah as madbreaks said above it's an async issue. I know the variable set in the $.post happens after. I guess I am trying to come up with a way to do an async call to the database, assign the value to a variable that I can then use throughout the rest of my script. More or less hold up the rest of the script until after the $.post is returned.

Comment: put the rest of your script in a function?  Then pass in the data as an argument to that function in the success function?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I am going to rethink this structure and maybe do that database query outside of JS in PHP before. Thanks agian

Answer (score 1):

You can store your whole data object instead of looping through and resetting the variable to a different value.  Then you can access all your data outside.  You should also define your variable outside of `$.post` so you have access to it

```
var cID;
$.post('URL', { }, function(data) {    
    cID = $.parseJSON(data);             
});
```